# PostgreSQL Install Fail in Windows 10 (icacls error )

Tags: postgresql

I am installing `postgresql-12.2-4-windows-x64` on Windows 10 and get the
following error.

How to resolve?

[image]

Comment: The installation file seems to be bad. Try to download it again.

Comment: I have tried, the same error.

Comment: The error message seems garbled. Are you sure you're downloading the right installer for your computer?

Comment: Yes ,I am sure. I installed it successfully in another win10 pc, I copied the installer in my pc, installed failed , I download installed ,failed again.

Answer (score 0):

If the same installer works on another computer but fails on this one with a very
garbled error message, then something is very wrong on the computer.
I suggest:

- Run `chkdsk` to check for disk corruption
- Run
  [SFC and DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- If nothing is found do
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I am Chinese, so my administrator account have Chinese character. It may be the reason. Someone say Chinese character influenc window temp folder,so I try to change temp location into d:/temp. I don't know if it has an affect. Thanks for helping ,but I am going to give up.

Comment: Yes, western software does not usually  support Chinese very well. You could temporarily change the language of the computer to English and see what happens.